# How to do async Button click using Jest in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am writing testcases for React application.
There is a login button that has to fire on submit. But i am understanding how would i do this async call and check if it it is success. This login function has a promise function inside.  I need to check the local Storage for token data as well.
Any help is appreciated.

```
it("renders LoginComp correctly", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<LoginComponent></LoginComponent>)
    const input_user = getByTestId('lg_username');
    input_user.value = 'admin';
    const input_pass = getByTestId('lg_password');
    input_pass.value = 'admin';
    const j = getByTestId('lg_btn').click();
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('tokenized'))
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There are helpers to wait for specific result. You should make your test function async to be able to use this. In your case I'd go with somethink like this.

```js
it("renders LoginComp correctly", async () => {
  ...
  await waitFor(() =>  expect( /* assert on the result or side effect of the async call */)
});
```

https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async

Comment: its showing waitFor undefined.... Also TOKEN_DATA is suppose to come after click.... How do i know what data is fetched? Only fetched data can be TOKEN_DATA

Comment: you should import `waitFor` before using it. I'm not familiar with the behavior of the `LoginComponent` but the philosopy of the testing library is to test what the user will see. Can't you make an assertion on some visible UI change? Also with jest you can make an assertion on calling the localStorage's set function. With that you will verify that you are wrinting something to the storage. For that you have to mock the function first, and you don't have to check the result. But I'd recommend not to check the implementation, and focus on the behavior.